# Massive spin one pseudovector decay?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, parity

Suppose you have a massive spin one pseudo-vector particle. Is it allowed to decay into an electron-positron pair? I'm thinking it might be disallowed because of parity conservation.

- If it is allowed, is a massive *vector* particle allowed to decay to a positron-electron pair ?
- Or are they both allowed ?

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose you have a massive spin one pseudo-vector particle. Is it
>   allowed to decay into an electron-positron pair?

Suppose you have fermion $\psi$ and pseudovector massive boson $G_{\mu}$. Phenomenologically you may write down two dimension-4 operators which mediate its decay on ff-pair:
$$
L_{\text{decay}} = c_{1}G_{\mu}J^{\mu} + c_{2}G_{\mu}J_{5}^{\mu},
$$
where 
$$
J_{5}^{\mu} = \bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_{5}\psi , \quad J_{\mu} = \bar{\psi}\gamma_{\mu}\psi
$$
The first operator violates parity symmetry, while the second saves it. So there is no problem into pseudovector decay on ff pair even if you require that $L_{\text{decay}}$ has to be parity symmetrical (i.e., $c_{1} = 0$).

So the decay is, of course, possible.

As for the vector boson decay, then you even have examples from the Standard model - $Z-$boson decay on electron-positron pair, which is mediated by operators
$$
L_{\text{decay}} = Z^{\mu}g^{e}_{L}\bar{e}_{L}\gamma_{\mu}e_{L} + Z^{\mu}g_{R}^{e}\bar{e}_{R}\gamma_{\mu}e_{R}
$$